# Spring Shared Queue as a Service

Tags: java, spring, queue

I want to implement a Service that stores data from another queue (SQS). 
First of all I defined Listener

```
@Component
public class MyListener implements MessageListener{


    @Override
    @JmsListener(destination = "my-queue")
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try{
            System.out.println(((TextMessage) message).getText());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*Just for testing the method prints only the payload of messages*

And now I want to define some sort of in-memory queue based on `LinkedBlockingQueue` as a `service`

```
public interface IStoreService {
    void save(Order order);
    String get();
}
```

The idea is that other services would be able to use `get()` method to fetch first message and use it. I think that this solution could reduce delay by creating a single endpoint where services could obtain some information or wait notification. Also it is only my hypothesis and I could misunderstand something.

And finally the question: How should I properly share this queue for one producer and multiple consumers?

**UPD1** (More information about the application).

It's standalone application that takes information (Let's say JSON object) from Simple Queue Service (Amazon). This logic is implemented in `MyListener` component. I also have another queue that has `Orders` and the queue is based on ActiveMQ (yeah, the architecture of the app is disgusting).

And here is the workflow:
`ActiveMQListener` fetches orders one by one from ActiveMQ queue and I want `ActiveMQListener` to grab first message from my `Storage` and let's say merge these two objects.

The only issue is how to share this storage between MyListener that fetches data from SQS and pushs it to storage and ActiveMQListener that fetches data from ActiveMQ.

And there is the demo code of the `StoreService`.

```
public class StoreService implements IStoreService {

    private final Queue<Order> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    @Override
    public void save(Order order) {
        this.queue.add(order);
    }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        Order order = queue.poll();
        return order.getId();
    }
}
```

**UPD2**
I faced with a problem while trying to solve the issue. As I mentioned above there are three queue:

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
|request.queue | - get information from ActiveMQ         |
|response.queue| - pass data to another ActiveMQ queue   |
|sqs.queue     | - queue based on Amazon SQS             |
+--------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I also have StoreService

```
@Service
public class StoreService implements IStoreService {

    private final BlockingQueue<Order> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    @Override
    public void save(Order order) {
        this.queue.add(order);
    }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        Order order = null;
        try {
            order = queue.take();
            return order.getId();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

ActiveMQListener with a method `receiveRequest`

```
    @JmsListener(destination = "request.queue")
    @SendTo("response.queue")
    public String receiveRequest(Order order){

        System.out.println("[INFO] REQUEST:" + order.getId());
        try{
            String test = storeService.get();
            System.out.println("[INFO] SQS:" + test);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return order.getId();
    }
```

*Sorry for System.out.prinln, I'v disabled logger*
As you can see this method gets information from queue called `request.queue` and also tried to obtain data from storeSerivce

Line: `String test = storeService.get()`

But the problem is that I have no idea how to pass storeService to it. I did something like this

```
    private StoreService storeService;
    @Autowired
    public ActiveMQListener Listener(StoreService storeService){
        this.storeService = storeService;
    }
```

And `storeService` is empty because it's only a new instance of `storeService`.

Any ideas?

**UPD3**
I also uploaded it to github [repository](https://github.com/nukede/titan-proxy). It's a little bit messy, but I think it's okay to understand the conception.

Comment: Could you please give some more information related to your question? You already defined an interface. The producer and the consumers could simply use it. What do you mean by "share" in your question? Do you need remote-access for example? What are your requirements?

Comment: @mm759, I added UPD1 section. Please, check it.

Comment: My candidate for an answer (hope I understand what you need): MyListener calls save on the StoreService when it receives data. ActiveMQListener calls StoreService.get to retrieve data. You need to add synchronized to the methods of the StoreService to avoid concurrency problems. What I don't understand is that StoreService.get only returns the ID. Don't you need the whole object so that you don't have to get it from elsewhere to achieve a reduced delay that you mentioned. Please note that using an in-memory storage can lead to loss of data in case of something like a server crash.

Comment: StorageServices only returns the ID because of testing. I'll implement it later. I tried to solve the problem, but I faced with the problem that I explained in UPD2 section.

Comment: @mm759, I also added github repo. Please, check it in UPD3 section.

Comment: Autowired should work. By default, Spring manages only a single instance. You have to use @Autowired in both listeners the that both get the one and only instance that is managed by Spring. The easiest way is to annotate the private property. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yep. I have already solved this problem. It works fine, but now I get an issue with connectionsfactory. Spring creates sqs.queue in the scope of activemq instead of connecting to the sqs.

Answer (score 0):

The StoreService can be injected by Spring using dependency injection like this:

```
@Autowired
private StoreService storeService;
```

This has to be done everywhere the service is used to get the one and only instance that is managed by Spring.